# Simplifying exponents: $a^x > a^y$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, branching-rules

Let's say that $a^x>a^y$ and $a>1$. You take the $\log_a$ of both functions and you get
$x>y$.

What if I wanted to do the same with $a^x+a^y>a^z$? Then I would get
$\log_a(a^x+a^y)>z$.

I wonder if $\log_a(a^x+a^y)$ can be shortened? Is there a rule that I am not aware of, or can I not do anything else? I am only wondering this in form of algebra, not computing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. To format your expressions, you can enclose them in dollar signs: `$a^x$` gives $a^x$. For more information, here's an excellent [formatting guide and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There's no simplification for the log of a sum.

Comment: The best you can hope for is something along the lines of: $\log_a(a^x+a^y)=x+\log_a(1+a^{y-x})$.

Comment: $0.5^2>0.5^3$ ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe "and a>1"

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm of a sum can only be expressed with infinitely many terms. Thus, you cannot shorten (by which I take you to mean reduce the amount of symbols in your sum) significantly. You may only lengthen it to infinity, if you please.